# IOS/Objective-C. Detect Press of Tab on Tab Bar Before Leaving View Controller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

For a settings view controller, I am currently saving when the user hits the Back Button using `viewwilldisappear`.  However, the settings VC is embedded in a tab bar controller and I've discovered that when the user leaves the VC by moving to another tab, `viewwilldisappear` does not fire and therefore the settings are not saved.  I guess I could save every time someone changes an individual setting, but it would be simpler to save at the end.

Is there any simple way to detect the press of the tab bar controller from *within* the view controller so I can save settings before leaving if a tab item is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at UITabBarControllerDelegate, specifically shouldSelectViewController.

> The tab bar controller calls this method in response to the user
>   tapping a tab bar item. You can use this method to dynamically decide
>   whether a given tab should be made the active tab.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate?language=objc

Comment: I included my tab bar controller in the interface of the VC and also implemented the uitabbarcontroller delegate protocol in the . h file.  IN turn, I included the method you mention in my implementation file.  The docs say something about setting delegate.  Following throws error. MainTabVC.delegate = self;
      In any case, the delegate method is not firing when I touch tab bar.

Comment: To be clear, you want your "settings" VC to be the delegate. I whipped up a quick sample project that should get you on your way: https://github.com/DonMag/OCTabbed